# Remap Capslock, but keep its function with Ctrl + Capslock

Tags: keyboard, 19.04, i3-wm, xmodmap, shortcut-keys

I want to remap my Capslock key to function as left mouse click, Alt+Capslock to function as right mouse click, and Ctrl+Capslock to function as Capslock.

I've been using this in Windows with AutoHotKey for a long time to help me click around faster with the laptop touchpad, but can't seem to find a way to do it in Linux.

Xmodmap won't work for this as Ctrl is not a native modifier key (at least, I haven't figured a way to work).

I've also tried xdotool, but the caps lock lock is also activated after I press it to click.

I'm running Ubuntu 19.04 with i3wm